# Area light creates whiteness only through glass

Tags: cycles-render-engine, materials, light, lighting, glass

So I have an animated scene where the camera goes through a window into a house. The only issue is that the ceiling of the house is white **(EDIT: it's actually not the ceiling, but the area lamp that's inside — see edit log at the bottom)** while the camera looks into it from outside and I have no idea why. On top of that, a character's head is partially cut off, too - only when rendered **through** the glass.

## PROBLEM:

[image]

[Rendered looking THROUGH the window]

---

[image: desc]

[Rendered from INSIDE]

---

## SCENE:

[image]

[This is what the scene looks like with the window plane hidden via "H"]

---

[image]

[These are the material properties of the glass. It's also been extruded.]

---

[image]

[And these are the materials of the house. Regular image textures UV unwrapped and assigned to the necessary faces.]

---

## RENDER SETTINGS:

GPU rendering
Cycles
1080*1920/25
Clamp direct: 1.11
Clamp indirect: 1.17
100 samples
Bounces: between 5 and 0; Diffuse: 2; Glossy: 2; Transmission: 12
1/50 motion blur
256*256 spiral

The rest is set to default.

---

If you have any idea on how to solve this, please share it with me.

## EDIT:

So I just realised that the whiteness might not be the house itself, but the **AREA LAMP that's inside**!! And the guy's head is cut off, since that part is in the physical area of the lamp object! Now the only thing I don't know is what to change. If I simply rised the lamp, it would cure the problem with the guy's head, but the whiteness would still be there. 
The lamp is - as I already said - an aerial light, its size is 3.433 , max bounces: 1024 , streght: 30

Comment: I'm not sure to what your whiteness refers, but if you mean noise, have a look at this question: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/4980/how-to-avoid-noisy-renders-in-cycles?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: **No, I do NOT have a noisy image problem. The problem with my renders is that a lamp with  an area type setting is VISIBLE in form of a white object when it is rendered BEHIND a solidified plane with a GLASS material.**

Comment: Lights in cycles are invisible to the camera, but they will be visible if they are reflected by glossy surfaces (like glass). Which leads me to ask: *Why do you need the glass in the fist place?* Unless you are looking for reflections on it, I would suggest just not to use it at all.

Comment: If you share your blend file more people might help https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/33324/emitter-object-shows-up-in-reflection-transmission

Comment: Well, I'll try that other question's ideas, but I want to clarify that I NEED glass, since, as I already said, the camera moves in through the glass, and since it has thickness, according to my expectations it should show a noticable effect because of the distortion (and there's grass outside of the house, so there are reflections, too).