# Light-emitting object showing in render

Tags: lighting

I have a light-emitting plane that shows up as a bright white reflection on a hero object as the object flies into view.

Is it possible to get the plane's light effect on the object without the plane itself being reflected in the object?

Am I trying to defy physics that even Blender can't do?

Comment: are you in Eevee or Cycles? do you mean a plane with an Emission node?

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/58318/how-to-have-emission-plane-light-the-scene-including-glossy-objects-but-not-show https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/33324/emitter-object-shows-up-in-reflection-transmission